# Link inside <a> element not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm not sure if many of you have tried to do this, and I'm completely out of ideas to solve this problem but here we go:

With a click of the button, a premade email comes up - but the link inside the email isn't a hyperlink! Check this out - the way I'm forced to do it is through javascript for control that I will be adding in later...

So the question is, how do I put a hyperlink (the link that is there should go to the link) in the email??

I guess that the real question is how I put html in that javascript...

Working jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/B29Bp/).

HTML:

```
<a id = 'emailoff' href = "" target = "_blank">
    <div id= "btn1">
         <h2 id = "enter">Send Email</h2>
    </div>
</a>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){
                $("#emailoff").attr("href", "mailto:" +
                                    "?subject=Your ThinOptics glasses &body=To get your new ThinOptics glasses simply click this link and pick the case and color you like best.  You'll get  free shipping on your order.%0D %0D http://www.Thinoptics.com/teddy@shalon.com%0D %0D Enjoy")
            });
```

Comment: It works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/djDm4/

Comment: why are there spaces in the subject?

Comment: Seems weird you are setting onclick that way

Comment: Works now: http://jsfiddle.net/B29Bp/2/ - Removed tartget _blank as it is useless for this. Added javascript void to href. encoded URL. Note that some clients, Outlook, require a ctrl+click to open the link.

Answer (score 3):

`mailto` links will be treated differently by different email clients.  Some may choose to convert the plain text beginning with `http://` to a hyperlink, while others do not.  In many situations (combination of mail clients, browsers an settings) a `mailto:` link will not work at all (I'm using the Chrome browser and use Gmail with no dedicated SMTP client installed, and the `mailto:` does not work for me at all).

> Mailto clickable links do not always function correctly for the site visitor. The software mechanism activated by the link requires that a default email client or webmail-service be established on the computer or in the browser. Not all web browsers, such as Internet Explorer, have the capability to configure a webmail service for this purpose, but only support local email client software. Others, such as Opera, Firefox, and Chrome, do have support for both variants.
>
> Additionally, if no email client or webmail service has been explicitly established to act as the default, one may still exist if an email client was pre-installed by the computer vendor but never used or configured by the user. In this case, upon clicking a mailto link, the user will be subjected to a volley of technical questions by the unconfigured email client.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto#Functionality_issues

Additionally, there are bots that routinely scan the web for `mailto:` links.  Expect to receive significant spam at any email address specified in that link.

Finally, make sure that you URL Encode required elements in the link

> [STD66] requires that many characters in URIs be encoded.  This
>      affects the 'mailto' URI scheme for some common characters that might
>      appear in addresses, header fields, or message contents.  One such
>      character is space (" ", ASCII hex 20).  Note the examples below that
>      use "%20" for space in the message body.  Also note that line breaks
>      in the body of a message MUST be encoded with "%0D%0A".
>      Implementations MAY add a final line break to the body of a message
>      even if there is no trailing "%0D%0A" in the body  of the
>      'mailto' URI.  Line breaks in other s SHOULD NOT be used.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6068.txt

Comment: So do you not think that what I am trying to do is possible?

Comment: I would not use `mailto`.  Standard practice is to use a form, which in turn can send an email.

Answer (score 0):

URL encoding the link could work.

```
<a href="http://www.google.co.uk/">Google</a>
```

Would be:

```
%3Ca%20href%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2F%22%3EGoogle%3C%2Fa%3E
```

It looks horrific, but you could try it if you're forced to do this.

[Try it here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)

Comment: or:  + would also be sufficient.

Comment: Some email clients will only create a text format email from a mailto link.  Such clients will not try to interpret the encoded HTML as such, but will simply present the encoded mess to the end user.